# SonarQube Javascript Remove the unused function parameter XYZ

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarjs

when analyzing my project I get quite a lot of false positives of type

> Remove the unused function parameter XYZ

for cases where a parent class has a method with parameters but the subclass doesn't require any but at runtime I don't know and don't want to know of what instance an object is and thus I wanna pass a parameter even if it is ignored due to method signature

Is there any chance to exclude such cases from Sonar reports?

```
class EdgeFinder{
    getNewEdgeMapEntry(face){} // it's bascially an abstract class to speak in Java terms and subclasses implement variations of some methods which the parent class defined but does not implement

...
}

class SingularEdgeFinder extends EdgeFinder{
   getNewEdgeMapEntry(face){
      return 1;
   }
   ...
}

class DifferentNormalsEdgeFinder extends EdgeFinder{
   getNewEdgeMapEntry(face){
      return [face.normal];
   }
   ...
}
```

And I create the instance of any class of edgeHelper at one point in the code and way later I execute the methods so I don't know at that point what was - or at least I don't want to care anymore - I know it's a subclass of EdgeHelper that's all I care for.

Comment: Please include a code sample. It's unclear to me how you would not know at runtime which arguments are being used and which not.

Answer (score 0):

When you use JavaScript classes, the methods of the inheriting classes do not need to have the same number of parameters as the method of the parent class. It works differently than you are familiar with from Java, there is no method overloading or anything like that.

In other words, it is perfectly OK to leave out the parameter if you don't use it, so your code example could and should be written like this:

```
class EdgeFinder{
    getNewEdgeMapEntry() {}
}

class SingularEdgeFinder extends EdgeFinder{
    getNewEdgeMapEntry() {
        return 1;
   }
}

class DifferentNormalsEdgeFinder extends EdgeFinder{
    getNewEdgeMapEntry(face) {
        return [face.normal];
    }
}
```

The “abstract” base class does not have to define any parameters in its signature, that is a concept from Java programming that doesn't exist in JavaScript. In fact, if you don't use the base class directly at all, it doesn't even make sense to define it:

```
class EdgeFinder {}
```